# Questions about the recessionary gap and inflationary gap graph

Tags: macroeconomics

In a recessionary gap and inflationary gap graph,

1. How can we know which aggregate expenditure curve is at full employment if it's not specified? Is potential GDP usually exogenous?
2. Where on the graph do we compare output and potential GDP? On the x-axis or within the curves?
3. Why don't we compare output with potential GDP, or GDP with potential GDP instead of comparing output with potential GDP? When we say  for example, that, if equilibrium occurs at an output < potential GDP, there would be a recessionary gap.
4. What does an equilibrium mean in this graph?
5. Why isn't an equilibrium occurring at an output>potential GDP positive?
6. Is there inflation at the equilibrium corresponding to full employment? If yes, and if it would increase unemployment, should an economy stay between AD1 and AD2 (see graph below)? If yes, then AD1 doesn't really include the best possible equilibrium, and wouldn't the economy be at equilibrium in that case?
7. In an inflationary gap, meaning equilibrium occurs where output>potential GDP, how are both output and prices high simultaneously?

Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: I assume you got this from [here](https://s-cool.co.uk/a-level/economics/aggregate-demand-and-aggregate-supply/revise-it/aggregate-supply)? In my opinion there are too many (basic) questions to be addressed in one question. WHat exactly is missing in the lenghty explanation of the website?

Comment: No, but thanks for the link!